# Same value then increment

Tags: excel, vba, increment

Im new to VBA and need help making a macro to basically see if the value is the same in the column and increment in another column. Bit confusing so heres an example:

```
INBOUND.T28 1
INBOUND.T28 2
INBOUND.T28 3
INBOUND.T28 4
INBOUND.T29 1
INBOUND.T29 2
INBOUND.T29 3
INBOUND.T29 4
INBOUND.T29 5
INBOUND.T30 1
INBOUND.T30 2
INBOUND.T31 1
INBOUND.T31 2
INBOUND.T31 3
```

Column A is already in the file, I want column B to print as above. Its basically counting the number of same values in A and restarting count when it a new value is found.

Im not really any good with VBA - although I have done Java in the past and based of that I know that I would need to use some kind of IF statement and a counter such as

```
value = value + 1
```

and maybe something like this to count?

```
Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + 1
```

Please help, I have no idea how to do VBA and learning it as I go :P Thanks! –

Comment: Where's your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 'INBOUND.T28' is in Column A and the `1` next to it in Column B then this formula should suit in `B2`:

> =IF(A1=A2,B1+1,1)

for the first row of data, if your first row is blank or labels. You can fill this and subsequent Column B rows with VBA with [Application.WorksheetFunction](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/callingworksheetfunctionsinvba.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I tried that and im getting a Circular Reference Warning. If i ignore that, It basically puts a 0 in column B until it gets to the last same value for which it pus a 1. 

Something like this

INBOUND.T58 0
INBOUND.T58 0
INBOUND.T58 0
INBOUND.T58 1
INBOUND.T59 0

Comment: Hi Pnuts, I put the formula in B2 and filled down - the output worked! But in B1 I had to manually enter "1"

THANKS SO MUCH! :)